# C++ how to convert ip address to bytes?

Tags: c++

How would I convert an ip address into bytes in C++? Basically how do I parse the IP address? For example, if I have a string equal to `121.122.123.124`. 
I need to parse this such that `byte1 = 121`, `byte2 = 122`, `byte3 = 123`, `byte4 = 124`.

Comment: `getline` with `.` as the delimiter would be worth looking into.

Comment: I have tried reading one char at a time, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to switch from byte1 to byte2 and so on once the '.' was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pattern is constant, number dot number dot etc, then use istringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4;
char dot;
char *ipaddress = "121.122.123.124";
istringstream s(ipaddress);  // input stream that now contains the ip address string

s >> byte1 >> dot >> byte2 >> dot >> byte3 >> dot >> byte4 >> dot;
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't need to set what dot is such as dot = '.'? Will this still work if the ip address is something like 12.34.56.123?

Comment: The >> operator is oveloaded such that it knows how to extract the data based on the type of variable you supply it. Since you supply a char (named dot) it extracts the dot as a char. dot is used simply as dots skipper. byte# is an int, so the >> will extract it as an int, no matter how many digits is has, so, yes, it will parse correctly.

Comment: This solution won't accept the valid input string "127.1", and won't reject the invalid input string "300.1.1.1".

Comment: Correct. See what I wrote at the very beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sscanf()` function:

```
#include <cstdio>

char arr[] = "192.168.1.102"; 
unsigned short a, b, c, d;
sscanf(arr, "%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Comment: Why are you manually NUL-terminating your strings? The compiler will do that for you, you know.

Comment: Yeah, you right. I've removed `\0` from the string literal. Thanks

Comment: This should be `unsigned char` (1 byte for each because it's IPv4). Not `unsigned short` which is misleading + a waste of memory and for sure the `%c` format specifier.

Comment: this code doesn't work if you change to %c or %hc.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`inet_aton`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton).

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string s;
  in_addr addr;

  while(std::cin >> s && inet_aton(s.c_str(), &addr)) {
    std::cout << inet_ntoa(addr) << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char ipstr[] = "121.122.123.124";
char *marker, *ret;
unsigned char b1, b2, b3, b4;
ret = strtok_r(ipstr, ".", &marker);
b1 = (unsigned char)strtod(ret, NULL);
ret = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &marker);
b2 = (unsigned char)strtod(ret, NULL);
ret = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &marker);
b3 = (unsigned char)strtod(ret, NULL);
ret = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &marker);
b4 = (unsigned char)strtod(ret, NULL);
```

Comment: This is tagged C++. Why all the C?

Comment: C solutions are usually better replaced with newer, C++ methods. Trying to just use C when you have C++ at your disposal is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @chris: Trying to use new methods just because they're new when you already have proven solutions that you are familiar with is a bit unnecessary.  I myself would prefer boost::split.  But if you're more comfortable with strtok, then you should use that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, it'd be a good idea to get into things that partners etc reading your code will know and love. It's always a good time to start learning something new that's commonly used (like `std::string` for example, which I must say is much better than a C array).