# creating boost::asio::ip::address_v4

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, ip

I'm not able to find a reasonable whitepaper that explains how to create `boost::asio::ip::address_v4`

for example:

```
// how to initialize address_v4 object?
address_v4 addr;   // with an IP address?

addr.from_string("192.168.1.100"); // does not work, see bellow

io_service io;
tcp::socket socket(io);
tcp::endpoint remote;
remote.address(addr);
remote.port(21);

// the rest...
```

according to boost documentation the constructor takes `bytes_type` or `unsigned long`.

Do I have to input address composed of individual bits or is there an easy way to specify the address?

program output:

> connecting to: 0.0.0.0
>
> connect: The requested address is not valid in
>   its context

BTW, is there some tutorial better than the one provided by boost web site?
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366631/c-how-to-convert-ip-address-to-bytes) that explains how you can convert a string-ip to bytes in c++.

Comment: `from_string` is a static method. Did you try `addr = address::from_string("192.168.1.100");`?

Comment: @SleuthEye Oh thanks, that worked! You can input an answer so I can accept it btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`from_string`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/from_string.html) is a static method, it does not update the value of `addr`.

To initialize `addr` from an IPv4 string in dotted decimal form you should instead use:

```
addr = address::from_string("192.168.1.100");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also speed things up by not parsing the string and set the address directly by using the [`address_v4` constructor that accepts `bytes_type`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/address_v4.html). E.g.:

```
address_v4 addr({192, 168, 1, 100});
```